# Difference between std::fstream::X and std::ios::X in C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am new to C++. I have simple question to ask you that what is the difference between `std::fstream::X and std::ios::X` open file mode in C++ ?

Where  `x` can be `in, out, ate, trunk, ate` ?

Here is more example:

```
fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

vs

```
fs.open(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
```

what is the difference between these two ?

Please don't answer in a complicated manner since I am beginner in C++.

Comment: It's inheritance working there

Comment: what does mean this ?

Comment: `ios` is base class of `fstream`

Comment: so what do it ? can so explain in more detail please.. with an possible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [Input/Output in File](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

> **class**: **default mode parameter**
>
> ofstream: ios::out
>
> ifstream: ios::in
>
> fstream: ios::in | ios::out
>
> For ifstream and ofstream classes, ios::in and ios::out are automatically and respectively assumed, even if a mode that does not include them is passed as second argument to the open() member function.

`std::fstream` is inherited from `std::ios`, according to this [page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)

When reading from a file, I prefer to use `std::ifstream::in` flag, because it could be a good programming practice to let a programming interface know what you are going to use it for.

Comment: what means inherited ?

Comment: @Aryan It means the `inheritance` in C++, one good resource is [here](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/inheritance/intro/)

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference. `std::fstream::X` is inherited from `std::ios`, so it's the same value as `std::ios::X`.

Answer (score 1):

Alice has a son, Bob. They both have the same hair color -- brown, let's say. Now, someone asks you: "What's their family's hair color?" You could say *Alice's* or *Bob's*: it's the same.

Can you see the point? Although the color is the same, Bob has *inherited* her mother's. It's the same for `std::ios::in` and `std::fstream::in` -- it's the *same* value, since they have an inheritance relation, but it's their "own" value because they are not the same type (likewise, Alice and Bob are not the same person).